# How can i make the response available outside the class?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How can i make the reponse to this available outside the class so it can be used application wide?

```
public void get_Data_home(final TextView tv) {

    //URL Builder
    String url_home = URL + URL_SERVICES + URL_VERSION + URL_HOME;

    final RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest postReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_home, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                jsonResponse = "";
                userAlias = "";
                for(int i = 0; i< response.length(); i++) {
                    String userName = response.getString("loginAlias");

                    userAlias += "Name: " + userName + "\n\n";
                }

                tv.setText(jsonResponse);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error [" + error + "]");

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Accept", HEADER_JSON);
            System.out.println(headers);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    request.add(postReq);
}
```

this is the networking i need to be used app wide.

I have tried to import the networking class into the MainActivity as a test but i cannnot seem to get the response of that to display as say a TextView?

Comment: Return it? Pass in something that implements an interface that does something with the response?

Comment: Change your method return type from `void` to `JSONObject `